# What are today's techniques to overcome the limitations of CAP theorem?

Tags: consistency, eventual-consistency, cap

Eric Brewer's theorem (1998), or CAP as most of the people refer to it, is one of the most known problems/limitations when designing big systems that require consistency, availability, and partition tolerance, when you only can achieve 2 of the three at the same time.

What are the best todays techniques to overcome this limitation, considering the one can't sacrifice one for the other two?

Answer (score 1):

Current thinking seems to agree that [Eventual Consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) is the best you can do, but that it's hard.

Other key words are 'Idempotent Messaging' - which is partly how eventual consistency is achieved.